# Conversion of Persian letters into English letters without translating words

Tags: php, google-translate

I want to convert persian letters to English letters in PHP and I don't want to translate them.
In Farsi we call it Finglish or Pinglish as you can see here:

for example :

```
سلام -> salam
اولی -> avali
معین -> moein
طلسم -> telesm
شعبده -> shobade
```

> Reverse of this is available in Google Translator
>
> please go to https://translate.google.com and make the first language Persian,
>   a button appears in the bottom of translate box with caption "چ" if
>   you click the arrow beside it, you'll see the conversion example :
>   salam
>   -> سلام , by enabling this button you can write in English and after pressing space it will become a Persian word.

I want to do that, like
Google, or use Google Api

Please help me

Comment: You won't get any algorithms here on SO since it is not a free coding service

Comment: I also do not want a complete algorithm, I need guidance on analyzing this issue.
 Or if you have a free service for this